PostgreSQL: Best practises for Deleting huge volume of Data in Replicated Environment
We have a prod database (PostgreSQL13) with a hot-standby(physical replication) as well as logical replication to a different subscriber server. Now we are in requirement of purging few year's record from some tables each having nearly 3-4M records for a month. All of these tables have timestamp field as well as PK and quite a few indexes.
Considering the WAL rate and possible replication lag what are the best solution to perform deletes in such an environment with minimal impact to client queries?

The best practice is to have thought about this requirement when you designed the database and to partition these tables by time range.
Then you can detach and / or drop the partitions with old data, which is fast and has no impact on the system.
If you didn't think ahead, you will have to run a massive DELETE, which will be followed by a massive autovacuum run that actually removes the data, and you are probably left with tables that have a lot of nothing in them. The latter problem is not so bad if you plan to fill up the tables again over time, but if you want to reclaim the space, you have to take down time and run VACUUM (FULL) on the tables.
An alternative is to create a new table that is defined like the old one and copy only the surviving rows into that table. Then you can drop the old table and rename the new one. This is usually the best method if you remove way more than half of your data, and you won't have any bloat. But it also requires down time.

Yes I understand if it was partitioned it could have a lot more easier. But it's not! For this time we can't go with partitioning. I am planning to perform few batches followed by a normal VACUUM and repeat. But a good batch size and whether to execute it through job or manual process yet to define.

It won't help at all to DELETE in batches. That can help with UPDATEs, since the next UPDATE can reuse the space freed by the VACUUM after the previous batch. But a DELETE doesn't create any new data, so the bloat will be just the same.

The idea of batches is to reduce replication lag for very long time and if i don't vacuum often it will result in a very long vacuum at end. Last time we had a problem with long running vacuum so I have to avoid it. The pages freed by VACUUM isn't it used by future inserts?

Sure, they are reused. If you want to do it in batches to avoid writing too much WAL in too short a time, that makes perfect sense. I was thinking you wanted to avoid bloat.

If I leave the table without a VACUUM FULL but only normal VACUUM, does it still cause heap/index scans take longer just like before the mass delete?

A sequential scan will have to read just as much from disk as before. But you'll have to process fewer rows, so it will be slightly faster.

The delete is based on a create_time field and hence I expecting all the tuples from those pages it touching will be removed. In this case all those pages will be updated as dead or frozen in visibility map? Could this help avoiding these pages during seq scan? One of our goal is to reduce the seq scan time substantially .

Sequential scan time won't be reduced substantially.
